# Javascript Auto Scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, scroll, auto

I would like to get this Auto scrolling code to go back up when it hits the bottom and just keep cycling up and down looping. Also would like to add a mouse over effect to pause it. Any help would be great.

```js
var interval = setInterval(() => {
  if ($("#div1").scrollTop() != $('#div1')[0].scrollHeight)
    $("#div1").scrollTop($("#div1").scrollTop() + 10);
  else clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
  This is a DIV<br>
</div>
```

Comment: _"Any help would be great."_ - you haven't told us what your actual problem is yet

Answer (score 0):

The `startScroll()` function is called initially on document.ready. It first retrieves the necessary dimensions of the div element (divHeight and scrollHeight).  If `scrollDirection` is set to `1` that means scrolling down and vice versa for `-1`. To pause and unpause you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` in jQuery. Below is the working snippet

```js
 var scrollAmount = 1;
var scrollSpeed = 5000;
var scrollDirection = 1; 
var paused = false;
var isMouseOver = false;
var scrollTimeout;

function startScroll() {
  var div1 = $('#div1');
  var divHeight = div1.height();
  var scrollHeight = div1.prop('scrollHeight');

  if (!paused && !isMouseOver) {
    if (scrollDirection === 1) {
      div1.animate({ scrollTop: scrollHeight }, scrollSpeed, function() {
        div1.scrollTop(0);
        startScroll();
      });
    } else {
      div1.animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, scrollSpeed, function() {
        div1.scrollTop(scrollHeight);
        startScroll();
      });
    }
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  startScroll();

  $('#div1').mouseenter(function() {
    isMouseOver = true;
    paused = true;
    $('#div1').stop();
  });

  $('#div1').mouseleave(function() {
    isMouseOver = false;
    paused = false;
    startScroll();
  });
});
```

```css
#div1 {
      height: 100px;
      width: 200px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      overflow: auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
     This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
    This is a DIV<br>
  </div>
```